# document.getElementById New Browser

Tags: javascript

I was use

```
document.getElementById("MyDiv1").style = "display:block";
```

for displaying MyDiv1 with javascript , That work on my pc but not work on other pc (mac) ,  Then I use :

```
MyDiv1.style.display = "block";
```

That work on other pc too ! But the error in the function...

The function before :

```
function Show(What){
document.getElementById("MyDiv1").style = "display:block";  }
```

The function that i right now use : ( Error )

```
function Show(What){
What.style.display = "block"; }
```

The Error Message :

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined
message: "Cannot set property 'display' of undefined"
stack: (...)
get stack: function () { [native code] }
set stack: function () { [native code] }
__proto__: Error
```

Comment: Can you show us a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demonstrating this?

Comment: How are you using `Show()`? What sort of values are being passed for `What`?

Comment: If an element with ID 'MyDiv1' is not found, *getElementById* will return *null*, and `null.style` will return *undefined*, hence your error references *undefined*. It seems the code may be executing before the element exists in the page, or an element with that ID doesn't exist at all.

Comment: I seriously doubt that `.style = "display:block"` ever worked ?

Comment: @RobG Correction: `null.style` produces an error, not `undefined`. If OP is getting the error "Cannot set property 'display' of undefined", then this would suggest that `What` has a value but does not have a `style` property.

Answer (score 0):

The "safe" way to write such functions is to check that the first method returns a suitable object before proceeding, so as a minimum you should do:

```
function show(id) {
  var el = document.getElementById(id);
  if (el) {
    el.style.display = "block"; // Consider using '' (empty string) instead
  }
}
```

Since if *getElementById* finds a DOM element, it will be returned and you can assumed that it will have a suitable *style* property. And if such an element isn't found, it returns *null* and the function does nothing (or you might choose to throw some kind of error).

Also, if you are hiding elements by

```
element.stlye.display = 'none';
```

then it's best to show them again by:

```
element.stlye.display = ''; // empty string
```

that way the element can adopt its default display property or whatever it inherits through CSS. Not all visible elements have a *display* of block, e.g. *span* is *inline*, *tr* is *table-row* or *block* depending on browser, and so on.

Comment: I was said document.getElementById(id) is doesn't work on another pc so i write id.style.display = "block"

Comment: The only browser I know of where *getElementById* doesn't work but using the ID as a global variable does is IE 4 (and maybe 5, not sure when MS introduced *getElementById*, but was there by IE 6). In that case, you can use *document.all*. But someone using a browser that old will have a very poor experience with modern web sites (likely they wont work at all).